# Not going when clicking on sections summary, list of table, list of figures, abbreviations

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, symbols, packages, acronyms

I am writing my master thesis in latex. However, when I click on the summary, foreword, list of figures, list of tables, and abbreviations resume in the table of contents, it goes to the wrong page.

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{varioref}
%\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
}
```

these are the packages i used in my thesis writing

```
\onsoz{\input onsoz.tex} %foreword
\abbreviations{\input abbreviations.tex} %list of abbreviations
\symbollist{\input symbols.tex} %list of symbols
\ozet{\input ozet.tex} %summary in english
\summary{\input summary.tex}
```

These are the files used at the beginning of the thesis.

```
\newcommand{\th@Summarypage}{
     \ChapterRightStayNumber
     \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-10\p@}} %AKC
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bf{\protect\abstractnameToC}} %AKC
     \vspace*{\UstenSpace}
       \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c}

         \th@titleFtSz\Baslikspacing \th@Titlebir \\
         \th@titleFtSz\Baslikspacing \th@Titleiki \\
         \th@titleFtSz\Baslikspacing \th@Titleuc \\
                  \\
         \th@titleFtSz\summaryname\ \\
                  \\
        \end{tabular}
       \end{center}
     \singlespacing
     \vspace*{-5mm}
     \sloppy
     \th@abstractStash % the actual abstract
     }
```

```
\newcommand\symbollist{
    \vspace*{\ChapterUstenSpace}
    \chapter*{\symbolname\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\symbolname}{\MakeUppercase\symbolname}}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-10\p@}} %AKC
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bf{\protect\symbolnameToC}} %AKC
    \vspace*{-20pt}
    \th@symbollistStash
    }
```

Above are the functions defined for the summary and symbols. If I can fix these two, I can handle the rest.

Comment: Note that you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example instead of these sniplets that others do not understand the context of. Note that the example should be self contained aka don't rely on files we do not have access to.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please provide a single block of code that can be copy-pasted by other people to test it, making it as short as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Does it make a difference if hyperref is installed before or after any macro using `\addcontentsline`?